# Pycharm environment files have disappeared

Tags: pycharm, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I'm working with Pycharm 2021.2.3(community edition) on ubuntu 18.04.6 with python3.8 and I'm using Nvidia GPU. When running a python file all my files disappeared. There are not even on the disk anymore. The interpreter is empty and the environment is apparently compromised. the locate command can see them, but the path is empty. See when I scroll on the files list below we can see the names but there are not existing anymore.
I started from scratch and it is running again.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a major bug and has been fixed in Pycharm 2021.3
track [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52053)